# Vuejs - Vuetify - Responsiveness lost after build but fine usign dev server

Tags: vue.js, responsive-design, vuetify.js

I am using Vuetify and the responsiveness works fine when I use the development server `npm run serve`.  I can resize the browser window and use my mobile devices to test. All the columns wrap as they are supposed to.

When I use the `npm run build` command the package is built and when I serve it now the responsiveness is not working. Everything just get smaller but no breaks as the window get smaller.

I am not even sure where to start thinking about this.

Comment: I am seing some css warnings in the console. I am confident it has something to do with the compilation of the css. A couple of css identifiers are being ignored as it is not found

Comment: May I know what version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try with adding "wrap" to the row tag. Sometimes it works fine without wrap and sometimes not. Also, add breakpoints to flex tags.
Here is an example code segment

```
<v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs12 md6>
          <h2>Element 1</h2>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12 md6>
          <h2>Element 2</h2>
        </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```